# How to get handle on each node to store/update certain values when using JAVA TREEMAP/any D.S

Tags: java, treemap

Let's say i want to store additional information in the Node() eg: number of nodes in left subtree and number of nodes in right subtree. Each insert/add that i call should eventually update these counters on the way. Problem is JAVA API'S don't provide this handle and only go an update this node.

Is there a way i can get a handle or provide some function which JAVA can call on each find of a node and within that function i can update those counters.

Answer (score 0):

For any given TreePath node we can use TreeMap.head or TreeMap.tail to get left or right side of the tree and then call size() on the returned structure to check the size of it.